# double accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

does anyone know if it is possible to do a double nested form for. so that i could upload images to a set from an article form.

e.g.

```
Article
  has_many :image_sets

ImageSet
  belongs_to :article
  has_many :images

Image
  belongs_to :image_set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Railscasts #196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1), looks like he sets up two levels of nested attributes, maybe you can do something similar to that.

Comment: perfect! don't know how i missed that. the nesting in rails is really smart :)